# How to remove all objects with the same name

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi how can i remove all objects with the same name, if i use:

```
local screenGroup = self.view
local randomBad3 = function()
  badC3 = display.newImage("BCloud3-"..tostring(math.random(1, 12))..".png")
  badC3.x = math.random (0, 450); badC3.y = -50-- -50
  physics.addBody( badC3, { density=.3, bounce=0.3, friction=.3, radius=25, filter=badc3CollisionFilter } )
  badC3.name = "BCloud3"    
  badC3.isSensor = true
  badC3.rotation = math.random(-30,30) -- Rotate the object
  trans5 = transition.to( badC3, { time= math.random(yForB3A, yForB3B), y=600,  transition=easing.OutExpo } )
  badC3.gravityScale = 0.0
  local cleanup
  cleanup = function()
   if badC3 then
       if badC3.y >590 then
           badC3:removeSelf()
           badC3 = nil
       end
   end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
end
randomBadC3 = timer.performWithDelay( math.random(1000, 5000), randomBad3, 0 )
```

--

```
   if badC3 then
           badC3:removeSelf()
           badC3 = nil
   end
```

it only removes the last spawned one, not all of them

Comment: Remove from where? You've given too little information on your problem.

Comment: Like Lorenzo said, there's far too little information to even begin to fathom what you mean. Do you mean to loop through a table and remove all instances of a value of badc3?

Comment: @kevin you know that objects and values in lua doesn't really have a name right?

Comment: @greatwolf well kinda using the name 'badC3' for a object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all images into one group when you want to delete delete entire group.

```
for i=1,#maingroup do
    if maingroup[i] then
        maingroup[i]:removeSelf();maingroup[i]=nil
    end
end
end
```